# How to make a slider in android like website?

Tags: android

I want to design the android application with slider(like website) when the user swipes from left to right or right to left I want to change the background not the whole view. I need a design like below. Please help me with native code samples

[image]

Comment: use viewpager. u can simply make the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this Library its may helps you

> https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/

Answer (score 0):

You can use View pager.

```
public class ImageDownloader extends Fragment {

    public ImageDownloader() {
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_image, null);
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        String imageUrl = bundle.getString("imageUrl");
        ImageView mView2 = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        ImageLoader mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(getActivity());
        mImageLoader.DisplayImage(imageUrl, mView2);
        return mView;
    }
}




    public class FragmentAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public FragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mdataStrings[position];
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("imageUrl", mdataStrings[position]);
        ImageDownloader mDownloader = new ImageDownloader();
        mDownloader.setArguments(bundle);
        return mDownloader;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return mdataStrings.length;

    }

}
```

And Use Like this :

```
                mdataStrings = GlobalVars.stories.get(pos)
                        .getUpload_images().split(",");
                mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
                FragmentAdapter titleAdapter = new FragmentAdapter(
                        getSupportFragmentManager());
                mViewPager.setAdapter(titleAdapter);
                for (int i = 0; i < mdataStrings.length; i++) {
                    LinearLayout mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.indicator);
                    ImageView mImageView = new ImageView(
                            StoriesDetails.this);
                    mImageView.setTag(i + "");
                    if (i == 0) {
                        mImageView
                                .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.black_circle);
                    } else {
                        mImageView
                                .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.white_circle);
                    }

                    mLinearLayout.addView(mImageView);

                }
                mViewPager
                        .setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onPageSelected(int page) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                System.out.println("Page : " + page);
                                LinearLayout mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.indicator);
                                mLinearLayout.getChildAt(page)
                                        .setBackgroundResource(
                                                R.drawable.black_circle);
                                for (int i = 0; i < mdataStrings.length; i++) {
                                    if (page != i) {
                                        mLinearLayout
                                                .getChildAt(i)
                                                .setBackgroundResource(
                                                        R.drawable.white_circle);
                                    }

                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0,
                                    float arg1, int arg2) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int page) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            }
                        });
```